# Speech Synthesizer for Apple Watch / WatchKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

Does anyone know if it is possible to access the built in speech synthesizer for the Apple Watch?

For my iOS main app I used `AVSpeechSynthesizer` as follows:

```
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:theSpeech]; 
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-GB"];
```

This works perfect but the same code doesn't work in the WatchKit extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per an answer in the [development forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1119198#1119198), audio playback does not appear to be possible directly on Apple Watch right now.

Playback for synthesized speech in a WatchKit Extension would take place on iPhone. This may not be a desirable user experience.

Comment: I am trying to use speech synthesizer on Apple Watch, It works sometimes and sometime it doesn't! Can you verify the link which answer on development forum has mentioned about it?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible.Here is described a small set of enabling WatchKit.
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/

Comment: Avoid pasting non-specific URLs, the one you posted is just the home page of WatchKit.